# Cannot convert value in record<ByteString, ByteString> branch of (sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or record<ByteString, ByteString>) to ByteString

Tags: api, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using .net 6 as a framework in my project .
I am using swagger ,so when I call my api I get this error in swagger :

```
Cannot convert value in record<ByteString, ByteString> branch of (sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or record<ByteString, ByteString>) to ByteString because the character at index 512 has value 8230 which is greater than 255.
```

Here is my Curl :

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:1010/api/v1/Sales/GetAllFinalizedAgentPaymentOrders?CustomerId=1&PayerCustomerId=1&PayerAgentId=1&CreatorUserId=1&InvoiceId=1&Statuses=1&Status=3&ReferralType=3&BranchId=12&PageNumber=0&PageSize=10" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Authorization: bearer ****"
```

[image]

I think the problem is because of token length .But I don't know how can I change the size of header request in .net .

My token :

```
bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijc5OThCRkUxRDg1NTBFRDVGQUEzRTJBNjgwRTU4MUZFIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2NTkzNDExMjcsImV4cCI6MTY1OTM2OTkyNywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9vYXV0aC1zdGFnZS5iZ2xvZ29uLmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6WyJza29ydWJhX2lkZW50aXR5X2FkbWluX2FwaSIsIkFydmFuaWsuRXhjaGFuZ2UuUGFuZWxfYXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFydmFuZXhfdnVlX2NsaWVudCIsInN1YiI6ImExNzQ0MmM2LWIyNjAtNDVlMC1hOWI5LWViOTliOGY0NDY3NiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTY1OTM0MTEyNiwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJuYW1lIjoiYWtiYXIuZWhzYWFuQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInNpZCI6IkI5OEI0OERCNDlDN…FQ0JDRTEwOTQ1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjU5MzQxMTI3LCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwicm9sZXMiLCJBcnZhbmlrLkV4Y2hhbmdlLlBhbmVsX2FwaSIsIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIl0sImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.zLZi4QyjJ_Bls95gEtW9yUkNd1zXWSP8Fh0Wjabjd5P6isUFiBegjImfZZC2ezZOqA7GWanTaoyMYaVR5OXWYzcXQ88oMh2b3sYbzgajQf1vdG-WNh0aKjnnJBMGrve76qNaR3shxWwix68FfIu8H4GNTv9vlnAqdF6M0x6TI1TcBwylc2V5CfddJ4CI8BeCF-D5dRZxvdKLzy9cRtsI6MPQwEn1HizEYsVB21M8K3QpeDxXV-hcY2Pd7MGB4q4GpzoR9l_3Uh51l52RfLODj5IRmh8vl8xSF8eVjhWWMcBrzUULTmpxaSx7SiLXs-elpsnQK80c2wUGNPsuiMWpuw
```

Comment: Add the token you are using to your question

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh I found the problem ,the token is not a valid token .but I don't know why ?

Comment: The reason is that your token contains non-ISO-8859-1 characters that are not allowed to be used in the header.

Comment: Just wanted to warn you, your email (akbar [dot] xxxxxxx [at] gmail [dot] com) is exposed in the JWT token.